# Ignored underscore letter

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

If i try to run "___sad" in the interpreter for the following grammar

```
grammar identTest;
options       

{   
    language = Java;
    output=AST;
}


goal: identifier;

fragment Letter: (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z'));
fragment Digit : '0' .. '9';
identifier :IDENTIFIER;


IDENTIFIER: Letter+;
WS:(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Interpreter output:
[image: interpreter]
Debugger output:
[image: debugger]

Interpreter includes underscore letter and debugger seems just ignores it! I expect to get some kind of exception in this case (since only 'A'-'z' letters are defined in the grammar). What is wrong with my grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the interpreter: it's buggy.

Using the debugger you can view the warnings/errors/exceptions your parser produces after pressing the <kbd>Output</kbd> button (lower left corner). When doing so, you will see the following:

```
.../__Test___input.txt line 1:0 no viable alternative at character '_'
.../__Test___input.txt line 1:1 no viable alternative at character '_'
.../__Test___input.txt line 1:2 no viable alternative at character '_'
```

The parser simply recovers from the underscores and continues parsing.

If you don't want your lexer to recover from such *no viable alternative* warnings, simply create a *fall through* lexer rule (called `OTHER`) and throw an exception from it:

```
grammar identTest;

options       
{   
    language = Java;
    output=AST;
}


goal       : identifier;
identifier : IDENTIFIER;

IDENTIFIER : Letter+;
WS         : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
OTHER      : . {throw new RuntimeException("unknown char: '" + $text + "'");};

fragment Letter : (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z'));
fragment Digit  : '0' .. '9';
```